How to get the pending transaction on the blockchain?
How to get the pending transaction on the blockchain ? Im trying to get the pending transaction on the blockchain, before it got validated, can someone help me ?

You can track pending transactions in Solana using the onSignatureWithOptions method from the Connection of Solana Web3.js library. By setting the commitment level to "processed", you can listen to transactions that have been received by the network but are not yet finalized.
Here’s a simple example:
const { Connection, clusterApiUrl, PublicKey } = require('@solana/web3.js');  
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');
const publicKey = new PublicKey("YourPublicKeyHere");  

connection.onSignatureWithOptions(  
    publicKey,
    (result) => {  
        console.log('Pending transaction:', result);  
    },  
    { commitment: 'processed' }
);

For more details, you can check out the documentation here: onSignatureWithOptions
